# How to make the grease pencil only draw the inner edges?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

I want to make my grease pencil only draw the inner edges of an object. How would I achieve this?

I am able to draw an outline around an object and even a line on all the edges, but I can't seem to figure out how to only draw a line on the inner edges.

I am using the Source Type "Collection", if it is not possible this way I can also use the object source type, but I'm trying to avoid that for now.

[image: Example of what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert the "silhouette" contour type:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much, that worked